# Force Mongoid to respect a "skip" criteria when destroying models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

In the [documentation for Mongoid querying](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html), the claim is made that Criteria#destroy will respect 'skip' and 'limit' criteria. I have not found this to be the case, and am wondering if I'm missing something.

Here's the query I'm running:

```
Vehicle.where(location_id: id).order(:mileage.asc).skip(100).destroy
```

My intention is to destroy all but the top 100 vehicle records attached to a location when sorted by mileage. The line above, when executed, deletes all vehicles attached to a location.

I am running this in a Rails app using Mongoid 2.4.12

Thanks!